# Ways to create a PKCS7 signature file using perl

Tags: perl, encryption, openssl, passbook, pkcs#7

I have been working on an application that create apples new ios pass.I am new to perl modules and i need some answers about how can we create signature files that uses PKCS7 encryption from a json file. any help would be appreciated.I have certificates and teamid for creating passes.
or 
more simply how to create a signature for a json file using PKCS7 encryption.

and have certificates of format p12 , pem cer.

Answer (score -1):

To handle PKCS7 you can use [OpenCA-PKCS7](http://search.cpan.org/~madwolf/OpenCA-PKCS7-0.3.0a/PKCS7.pm) module. To deal with JSON you can use [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.57/lib/JSON.pm) module. CPAN documentation gives all the needed info to work with those modules. Enjoy.

Comment: That module just reads the signature file, and lets you view the signer.  it does NOT generate signatures.